# How to handle Node.js performance impact of HTTP request

Tags: node.js, performance, express, load

I build a simple API Gateway / BFF in Node.js which listens at a port and calls two other services.

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')

const app = express()


app.get('/', (request, reply) => {
    const promise1 = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/p')
    const promise2 = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/s')
    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(([res1, res2]) => {
    reply.send('done')  
    })
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.info(`server listening`)
})
```

This endpoint is supposed to handle a moderate load (e.g 500 requests / second).

On my local machine, using load testing tools, this endpoint cannot serve more than 100 requests / second, while if I don't do any HTTP request and return just a plain JSON, the requests which can be served are around 10000. CPU seems to be the bottleneck.

Is there any way to improve performance here that I am missing?

Comment: I'm actually starting to think more than the CPU, the issue is available sockets. I noticed that setting `httpAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });` has a 2x performance improvement. However, it's still too low for what I'd expect